# Adding items to ArrayList in a loop

Tags: java, arraylist

So i'm trying to add items (which have to be static) to an ArrayList using this class template:
AllEventInformationStatic.java:

```
public class AllEventInformationStatic {

    public static int id;
    public static String name;
    public static String type;
    public static String date;
    public static String desc;
    public static String location;

    public AllEventInformationStatic(int id, String name, String type, String date, String desc, String location)
    {
        AllEventInformationStatic.id = id;
        AllEventInformationStatic.name = name;
        AllEventInformationStatic.type = type;
        AllEventInformationStatic.date = date;
        AllEventInformationStatic.desc = desc;
        AllEventInformationStatic.location = location;
    }
}
```

AllEventResponseStatic.java:

```
public class AllEventResponseStatic {
    public static ArrayList<AllEventInformationStatic> events;
}
```

And here is the iteration to fill the ArrayList:

```
AllEventResponseStatic.events = new ArrayList<AllEventInformationStatic>();
for (int i = 0; i < allEventResponse.events.size(); i++)
{
    AllEventResponseStatic.events.
            add(new AllEventInformationStatic(42, "bowling",
                    "event", "11/12/2015",
                    "enjoy it", "paris"));

    String name = AllEventResponseStatic.events.get(0).name;
}

String name_bis = AllEventResponseStatic.events.get(0).name;
```

So the variable name display "bowling" but name_bis is Null.
it seems like it just clear the whole arraylist after the iteration and I have don't know why..

If you have any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Just double checking that you know what's the differences between declaring a variable as `static` and not doing so.

Comment: Please show the actual code.  There's no way that what you've posted will give the outcome you're describing (also, it works as expected for me when I paste your code into eclipse).

Comment: But I got to declare the variable as static to get them from other class, so how should I do?

Comment: @Chris no you don't, you just need an instance of AllEventInformationStatic. As things stand, every time you create a new instance of it, you will overwrite the current field values.

Comment: @Chris : I've remove the Android tag from this question as there is nothing directly related to Android in it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean allEventResponseStatic in loop condition and not allEventResponse.

```
 AllEventResponseStatic.events = new ArrayList<AllEventInformationStatic>();
```

**After this call the size of list is zero so loop is never called. Hence you get null on index 0 after the loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < allEventResponseStatic.events.size(); i++)
{
    AllEventResponseStatic.events.
            add(new AllEventInformationStatic(42, "bowling",
                    "event", "11/12/2015",
                    "enjoy it", "paris"));

    String name = AllEventResponseStatic.events.get(0).name;
}
```

Also, please research what **static** keyword does, as it is useless here and causes far bigger problems in your code.

Comment: Actually allEventResponse is another class which contains an arrayList also, but I think I'll check something else to use instead of static variables.